# C# setting new values to array

Tags: arrays

How can I rewrite all values in array? For example I have array:

```
 int[] polyX = { -22, 21, 166, 174, 106, 33, 20, 14, -30, -19, -24 };
```

And now I want to set these values:

```
polyX = { -43, 5, 23, 65, -64, 33, 4, 14, -30};
```

Is it possible to set new values to arrays like to any other variable?

Comment: Can you use polyX.ToArray() or is this for a homework problem?

Comment: I can but im no familiar to that method.

Comment: take a look to array class documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The second set of values are identical to the first. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I could create different array variable but it would take more time since I would need about 100 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your second line. It should actually be:

```
polyX = new[] { -43, 5, 23, 65, -64, 33, 4, 14, -30, -3, -321};
```